# get image by position and resize

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images, image-resizing

I need to get images by its position and I need each image resized to a concrete heigh and width.

If I want a image by its position I can do it by this code:

```
$_product
    ->getMediaGalleryImages()
    ->getItemByColumnValue('position', 1)
    ->getUrl();

//get image at position 1
```

And I know how to resize an image with this code:

```
echo $product
        ->helper('catalog/image')
        ->init($_product, 'image')
        ->constrainOnly(true)
        ->keepAspectRatio(true)
        ->resize(900, 400);
```

But this code resizes the image set as image (or thumbnail, or small_image) but I don't know how to resize the image set at certain position (for example 2).

How can I merge both codes to resize the image at a certain position?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution, this works, at least in the catalog/product/view templates:

```
<?php
    $_imgSize = 630; 
    $_imgSizeHeight = 945;
?>
<?php $i=0; foreach ($this->getGalleryImages() as $_image): ?>
    <?php if ($this->isGalleryImageVisible($_image)): ?>
        // at 'position default' set the number of the position you need
        <?php if($_image['position_default'] == 1): ?>  
            <a class="product-view-gallery" data-fancybox="gallery" data-caption="<?php echo $_product->getName(); ?>" href="<?php echo $this->getGalleryImageUrl($_image); ?>"><img id="image-<?php echo $i; ?>" class="gallery-image" src="<?php 

                echo $this
                        ->helper('catalog/image')
                        ->init(
                            $this->getProduct(), 
                            'image', 
                            $_image->getFile()
                        )
                        ->constrainOnly(true)
                        ->keepAspectRatio(true)
                        ->keepFrame(false)
                        ->resize($_imgSize, $_imgSizeHeight);

             ?>" data-zoom-image="<?php echo $this->getGalleryImageUrl($_image); ?>" /></a>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php $i++; endforeach; ?>
```

Maybe it helps somebody in the future